# FFMPEG Image Zoom to a Position X Y

Tags: ffmpeg, images, coordinates, positional-parameter

I need to zoom to a special point of an image.
What do i have to change in this existing Script for example Y:81% X:27%?

```
 ffmpeg -r 25 -i image.jpg -vf 
"zoompan=z='zoom+0.001':x='if(gte(zoom,1.5),x,x+1)':y='y':d=125\"
 -y -shortest -c:v libx264 output.mp4 -y
```

[image: Image Example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i image.jpg \
       -vf "zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.01,2.5)':x='iw/2-iw*(1/2-27/100)*on/150-iw/zoom/2':y='ih/2-ih*(1/2-81/100)*on/150-ih/zoom/2':d=150" \
       -c:v libx264 output.mp4 -y
```

`150` is the duration of the zoom (and the movie), and it zooms from the centre to the target point. `zoompan` won't generate smooth motion if the animation is short, so consider increasing the length.

Comment: Seems to work, but even with higher duration not smooth . i tried to change all "150" nums with 400, but  even uglier then before :-(

Comment: You did change `on/150` to `on/400`?

Comment: yes, like you described... https://youtu.be/Qjn1LlLUZqM

Comment: Ok i just upscale it with no jiggle effect: ffmpeg -i image.jpg -vf \"scale=8000:-1,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':x='iw/2-iw*(1/2-88/100)*on/150-iw/zoom/2':y='ih/2-ih*(1/2-94/100)*on/150-ih/zoom/2':d=150\" -c:v libx264   -t 5 -s \"800x450\" output.mp4  -y